# Python boto: filter on tag and value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

Filtering by tag key works just fine:

```
ec2.get_all_instances(filters={'tag-key': 'MachineType'})
```

How can I filter by key and value?

```
"MachineType=DB"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Boto**

```
ec2.get_all_instances(filters={"tag:MachineType" : "DB"})
```

**Boto3**

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
inst_filter = [{'Name':'tag:MachineType', 'Values':['DB']}]
insts = list(ec2.instances.filter(Filters=inst_filter))
for inst in insts:
  print inst.id
```